# SSIS error NText to varchar(255) SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

I am trying to use the Slowly Changing Dimension in the SSIS, but only for one column it is not working, I've tried everything possible.

> I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

the column: requisitionnotes in Microsoft Access is LongText, in SQL Server is NText, how can I convert it?

Should I change the dataformat in SQL Server?

> Error 1   Validation error. tblRequisitions: tblRequisitions: The
>   "Slowly Changing Dimension.Inputs[Slowly Changing Dimension
>   Input].Columns[requisitionnotes]" has a long object data type of
>   DT_TEXT, DT_NTEXT, or DT_IMAGE, which is not supported. 
>     Migration.dtsx  0   0

Comment: Try using `Data Conversion` transformation.

Comment: I have tried many times. However, it is not converting it.. How can I just cut the string, and convert to varchar(255)?

Comment: What are you using as your source? OLE DB?

Comment: Yes, from Microsoft Access, then I have a sort component, and then the Data Conversion.

Comment: Assuming you are using "Table or View" as your "data access mode" in your OLE DB Source, click the "data access mode" for drop down and choose "sql command"  then write `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), [columnName]) FROM Table` once sql editor comes up...If that doesn't work, your going to have to create a derived column transformation...I don't have SSIS in front of me so am doing by recall...sorry for no screenshots

Comment: I tried, however, SSIS, doesnt work still, so I ended by removing this field.. I will try to import only necessary fields, my problem now is the speed of the Slowly Dimension component, I have to sincronize in real time 320.000 records, it is going to be impossible using SSIS. :(

Comment: NText? What version of sql server are you using? unless you are using a version older then 2008, [microsoft suggest replacing ntext with nvarchar(max)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Create a `Derived Column` transformation....in expression box try adding this `(DT_I4)[Your Column]`  and replace the column and rename it.  then youse that derived column to map

Comment: Yes it is Ntext @ZoharPeled. SQL Server 2012, Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I will try with Derived Column @JeffOrris

Comment: @RogerOliveira: Did you read the link I provided in the last comment?

Comment: Roger, the SCD component is indeed very slow. On one of the MS training courses, I was advised to try using MERGE statements instead - there's good information online about using them for SCDs. I still often use SSIS (for instance, you could move the data from the source to a staging table, and carry out necessary conversions and other transformations), but then jump from my final staging table to the target via a merge - use an execute SQL task to hold the merge or call a stored procedure which carries out the merge.

Comment: There is also a few third party SCD components (https://dimensionmergescd.codeplex.com/) that are superior to the Microsoft one. I'm convinced the Microsoft one was written by the work experience kid.

Comment: You should be using Visual Studio 2010 to develop SSIS packages for SQL 2012.

Comment: Does Visual Studio 2010 allow me to use this third party SCD component? @TabAlleman

Comment: I wouldn't know, it should be in the component's documentation.